# Can't find Json file inside project

Tags: c#, json, file, windows-phone-8, readfile

I'm trying to read a json file from my project but vs can't find it. When I'm using the `.txt` extension, everything is OK, but when I change extension to `.json`, then the file is not found

```
string fileContent;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Resources/Database/text.json"));
using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
fileContent = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();
```

> "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use JSON file, you need to right click on the file in file explorer in Visual Studio and choose Properties, then in Advanced section:

1) set `Build Action` to `Content`

2) set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`